# Format of pg_auth/pg_pwd file

Tags: postgresql, pgbouncer

When setting up pgbouncer, you need to create an auth file, "The file format is the same as the PostgreSQL pg_auth/pg_pwd file". What is this format? Trying to google yields pages of this sentence. http://www.google.com/search?q=pg_pwd+auth+file+format&oq=pg_pwd+auth+file+forma

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your pgbouncer.ini

```
auth_type = trust
auth_file = /etc/pgbouncer/userlist.txt
```

In userlist.txt

```
"username" "password"
```

Note the quotes. See http://pgbouncer.projects.pgfoundry.org/doc/config.html#_authentication_file_format